# Flutter provider dispose

Tags: flutter, dispose, provider, navigator

I have a provider used in different pages managing by `Navigator`

I created the provider in the first router:

```
class FirstPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  static MyProvider myProvider = MyProvider();
  const FirstPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<FirstPageRouter>(
            create: (context) => FirstPageRouter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
          create: (context) => myProvider,
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer2<FirstPageRouter, MyProvider>(
        builder: (context, model, myProvider, child) => Scaffold(
          appBar: MyAppBar(model),
          body: Body(model, myProvider),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can not recreate MyProvider. This provider connect to a hardware port and I can not recreate it in each page. So I used the same provider in the next page:

```
class SecondPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  static MyProvider myProvider = MyProvider();
  const SecondPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SecondPageRouter>(
            create: (context) => SecondPageRouter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
          create: (context) => FirstPageView.myProvider,
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer2<SecondPageRouter, MyProvider>(
        builder: (context, model, myProvider, child) => Scaffold(
          appBar: MyAppBar(model),
          body: Body(model, myProvider),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that when I back and pop the navigator `Navigator.of(context).pop();` in each page, Flutter dispose `FirstPageView.myProvider`. How can I prevent dispose of provider and keep using it in all pages?

Answer (score 0):

> Wrap the root of the app with MultiProvider. Generally the root of the app is MaterialApp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You mean:
`Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        create: (_) => LanguageChangeProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<LanguageChangeProvider>(
        create: (_) => LanguageChangeProvider()),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}`
I do not to need any `Consumer`?
The problem is that I dont recive any notification when I `watch`. Do you know where the issue come from?